# mysql - join where right hand table has ALL required

Tags: mysql, sql

I have t1:

```
vid  vs
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     2
2     3
3     1
3     3
```

and t2

```
pid  ps
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     3
```

I need ONLY t2.pid, t1.vid where all required t1.vs are in t2.ps for the respective t2.pid:

```
pid  vid
  1    1
  1    2
  2    1
  2    3
```

So, vid 3 is not selected for pid 1 as ps 2 is not in vs...

I'm getting tangled up in joins here... Help?

Comment: Can you show your current query?

Comment: `right outer join` is what keeps all values of right hand side table!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `pid`s that meet this condition in various ways.  Here is one:

```
select t2.pid
from t2 left join
     t1
     on t2.pid = t1.vid
group by t2.pid
having count(*) = count(t1.vid);  -- all are present
```

You can then use this in a query to get what you want:

```
select t2.*
from t2 join
     (select t2.pid
      from t2 left join
           t1
           on t2.pid = t1.vid
      group by t2.pid
      having count(*) = count(t1.vid)
     ) tt2
     on t2.pid = tt2.pid;
```

Finally, you could get the `ps` values as a list, just using aggregation:

```
select t2.pid, group_concat(t2.ps)
from t2 left join
     t1
     on t2.pid = t1.vid
group by t2.pid
having count(*) = count(t1.vid);  -- all are present
```